# de-serializing error in asp.net mvc control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid, and by using `getRowData` I am fetching jqGrid data. After that I am applying `JSON.stringify(rowData)` and finally I get the result as:

```
[
    {
        "FIRST_NAME": "Krish",
        "LAST_NAME": "Patil",
        "EMPLOYEE_TYPE": "Consultant",
        "TITLE": "Application Resource",
        "LOCATION": "USA ",
        "CENTER_NAME": "Application Development & Testing",
        "EMAIL": "goal@test.com",
        "COMMENTS": "testing"
    }
]
```

It's working fine as expected in 'JavaScript'. However, once I am sending this data to the controller and tried to de-serialize it I am getting an un-terminated string error `"CENTER_NAME":"Application Development ..` 
Due to the '&'(special character) it's happening. How do I resolve this, please advice on the same.

------De-Serialization code ------------

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 UserData result = ser.Deserialize<UserData>(userData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to verify the type of `userData` which you use. You don't posted more full ASP.NET MVC code which you use. I suppose that the data (the variable `userData`) are already deserialized to object by ASP.NET MVC. JSON specification (see [here](http://www.json.org/)) is very simple. Only `"` and `\` characters *must be* escaped. There are some other characters which *could be* escaped (like `/` for example). I can't imagine that `JavaScriptSerializer` could have a bug with wrong processing of `&` character.

**UPDATED**: One possible bug in your code is *what is* the `UserData` class which you use. Probably the code should be

```cs
List<UserData> result = ser.Deserialize<List<UserData>>(userData);
```

instead of

```cs
UserData result = ser.Deserialize<UserData>(userData);
```

because you send array of items. In any way the program with the code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DeserializationTest {
    public class UserData {
        public string FIRST_NAME;
        public string LAST_NAME;
        public string EMPLOYEE_TYPE;
        public string TITLE;
        public string LOCATION;
        public string CENTER_NAME;
        public string EMAIL;
        public string COMMENTS;
    };

    class Program {
        static void Main () {
            const string userData = "[{\"FIRST_NAME\": \"Krish\",\"LAST_NAME\": \"Patil\",\"EMPLOYEE_TYPE\": \"Consultant\",\"TITLE\": \"Application Resource\",\"LOCATION\": \"USA \",\"CENTER_NAME\": \"Application Development & Testing\",\"EMAIL\": \"goal@test.com\",\"COMMENTS\": \"testing\"}]";
            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = ser.Deserialize<List<UserData>>(userData);
            Console.WriteLine("result[0].CENTER_NAME={0}", result[0].CENTER_NAME);
        }
    }
}
```

works **without any exception** and it displays the following text on the console:

```
result[0].CENTER_NAME=Application Development & Testing
```